# jquery mask dependent on drop down value

Tags: jquery, masking

I'm using the jquery mask from Digital Bush: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

I have a customer signup form which references a mask, however since my customer base is both in the U.S. and Canada I need the mask for postal/zip code to change:

Current mask rules:

```
    $(function($){
jQuery(function($){
   $("#postal_code").mask("a9a-9a9");
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

The form is pretty standard and follows the following format:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" />
```

I was hoping someone could explain to me how I could change the $("postal_code").mask("a9a-9a9"); to $("postal_code").mask("99999");
when United States is selected from the drop down list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work I guess...

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if ($selected.val() === 'US') {
        $("#postal_code").mask("99999");
    } else {
        $("#postal_code").mask("a9a-9a9");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Please see the working version here - I made a jsFIddle for you. it works according to your need.

you need to use **unmask property** before remask it here (previous link was dud.

http://jsfiddle.net/XJZvJ/33/

```
$('#country').change(function () {

    if ($('#country option:selected').val() == 'US') {
       $(".postal_code").unmask("")
        $(".postal_code").mask("99999");

    } else {
        $(".postal_code").mask("a9a-9a9");
    }
});
​
```

This will help; cheers

Comment: no worries man! lol spent some time to build it for you when you asked, but I reckon I missed you by few minutes, make sure you use unmask else there will be some weird behavior, have a good one, cheers